# Dataframe: group with an discontinuous column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a dataframe like following, and I want to separate each continuous part from other parts.That means, every zero 'diff' will be grouped with the last non-zero item of the same name. The result should be: group1: `('E', (1,2,3))`; group2: `('E',(4,5))`; group3: `('C',(1,2))`.

How can I do this? Thanks a lot!

```
+----+----+------------+
|name|diff|num_in_group|
+----+----+------------+
|   E|null|           1|
|   E|   0|           2|
|   E|   0|           3|
|   E|  40|           4|
|   E|   0|           5|
|   C|null|           1|
|   C|   0|           2|
+----+----+------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic_group = {}

new_group = True

counter = 0

for index in df.index:

    if new_group == False:

        if df.loc[index, 'diff'] == 0: 

            dic_group[ref_name]['numbers_in_group'].append(df.loc[index, 'num_in_group'])

        else:

            new_group = True

    if new_group:

        counter = counter + 1

        ref_name = 'group%d' %counter

        dic_group[ref_name]={}

        dic_group[ref_name]['name'] = df.loc[index, 'name']

        dic_group[ref_name]['numbers_in_group'] = []

        dic_group[ref_name]['numbers_in_group'].append(df.loc[index, 'num_in_group'])

        new_group = False
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'group1': {'name': 'E', 'numbers_in_group': [1, 2, 3]},
 'group2': {'name': 'E', 'numbers_in_group': [4, 5]},
 'group3': {'name': 'C', 'numbers_in_group': [1, 2]}}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your answer! What I have described is only an example, the table can be very large (over 1.8 billion rows). Is there any more efficient way in spark?

Comment: dont think so. usually groupby is an easy/fast/friendly solution. but you are breaking  the groups periodically.. you could use tqdm library to get a good estimation of how long it wld take for that loop to go by:  "from tqdm import tqdm, and use for index in tqdm(df.index):"   ps: upvote me bro :p

Comment: yeah, groupby would be a good method. Those rows should come from different files, but the file name is lost in the transformation, so I have to deal with this hot potato. Anyway, thank you for your answer!